# Find all building lat/long coords within a polygon

Tags: maps, coordinates, reverse-geocoding

I have a polygon of lat/long pairs. I want to somehow build a list of addresses and after research I know this is going to be extremely difficult. I know there is not a way to automatically do this from any service.

From what I understand I could try to build a database with addresses and lat/long coordinates and match them against all possible points within the polygon. That would be great if I could easily find free data like this. The closest thing I can find is http://openaddresses.io which is still very incomplete and I need the whole US.

Is there a service (software, online, API) that can at least find all buildings in a polygon? I could at least then reverse geocode the point and get the address out if it's valid.

Can anyone suggest anything to help achieve my end goal of finding all addresses in a polygon? The only requirement really is it needs to be free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the resorces, you can program it yourself. Just use a formula that calculates if a given point is inside of a polygon and adapt it to work with your coordinates.

I had a similar problem. My app needed to check the neighborhood in wich a latLgn was included. The Wikimapia API returned me all neighborhoods within a radius, but not wich one had the coordinate within it´s boundaries.

I had to adapt the function myself, because the API didn´t do it (although it provided me with all the data necessary to extract the information).

Here´s the function I made. (in C#)

```
    public bool NoPoligono(PointCollection poligono)
    {
        bool result = false;
        Point local = new Point(double.Parse(this.Lng, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(this.Lat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        int j = poligono.Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < poligono.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(poligono[i].Y) < Math.Abs(local.Y) && Math.Abs(poligono[j].Y) >= Math.Abs(local.Y) || Math.Abs(poligono[j].Y) < Math.Abs(local.Y) && Math.Abs(poligono[i].Y) >= Math.Abs(local.Y))
            {
                if (Math.Abs(poligono[i].X) + (Math.Abs(local.Y) - Math.Abs(poligono[i].Y)) / (Math.Abs(poligono[j].Y) - Math.Abs(poligono[i].Y)) * (Math.Abs(poligono[j].X) - Math.Abs(poligono[i].X)) < Math.Abs(local.X))
                    result = !result;                 
            }
            j = i;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It belong to a class named Ponto, that represented a coordinate in my application´s logic. It served to validate if it was inside of the polygon (PointCollection) passed as a parameter.